# GODOT set of attack movements

Tags: pixel, game-development, godot, 2d-games

As you can see in many games, when your characters perform multiple attack moves just by simple clicks. For example, first click is normal attack, second click (right after first click) is still normal attack but different move, third click (after 2 first clicks) is also normal attack but maybe more special, etc. Something like that. So how do you guys code it? My game is 2D pixel. Coded by GODOT.

I have searched for many methods but maybe I don't have enough experience to conduct correct investigation. If you know something please share. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a finite state machine where the player can enter the attacking state by pressing the attack button where the player will then execute a normal attack, then have additional states that can only be entered if the player is in the previous attack state and give each of these additional states new attacks.

Additionally, a timer could be added so a successive attack can still be entered for a short period of time after the attack

Finite state machines are also just generally useful when creating characters

Something like this in pseudocode:

```
IdleState() {
    if attackButton.isPressed() {
        EnterAttackState1()
    }
}

AttackState1() {
    //Normal Attack Code
    if attackButton.isPressed() {
        EnterAttackState2()
    }
    if attackIsOver {
        EnterIdleState()
    }
}

AttackState2() {
    //Attack 2 Code
    if attackButton.isPressed() {
        EnterAttackState3()
    }
    if attackIsOver {
        EnterIdleState()
    }
}

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a log of clicks.

```
var clicks = 0; 

onclick = function(e) {
     if (clicks == 0) {
         doAttack1Animation(); clicks = 1; return;
     }
     if (clicks == 1) {
         doAttack2Animation(); clicks = 2; return;
     }
     if (clicks == 2) {
         doAttack3Animation(); clicks = 0; return;
     }
}
```